# Where to find my local Git configuration?

Tags: git, github

I inherited a server from a former co-worker and it looks like his Git configuration is somewhere in the server (his account is deleted). When I run the following command,

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

This returns the following with the former coworker's name.

```
Hi JohnDoe! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I tried different things like "git config --list", "git config --glocal --list" and so on but I couldn't find where this is stored. I removed ~/.git-credentials but that didn't help.

Any insight on this?

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with Git itself. It's a bit of sneakiness done by GitHub, using the ssh key you present to them. They look it up and see that only JohnDoe knows *that* key, so you must be JohnDoe. Where did you get the ssh key you are using?

Comment: you should recreate a new ssh key

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of `~/.ssh`

If you see an `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`, remove them.
Then follow the "[Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)" guide, and generate your own new set of SSH keys (register the `id_rsa.pub` content to your GitHub account)